# jQuery promise iteration

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an array I need to loop through and send an ajax call with.  However I would like it to happen serially (Do the next after the previous was done successfully).  How do I go about doing this efficiently??

```
$($('.logitem').get()).each(function(i,item) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/save.php',
        data: {myData: $(item).html()}
      });
});
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you want your ajax request to happen only once the previous ajax request completed successfully?

Comment: Correct..............

Comment: What Javascript version are you targeting? ES6 ok?

Comment: @GabrielBourgault Sure es6!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I don't know how efficient this solution is really, but it does seem to work from my tests.

The main idea is to use a generator to iterate over your list of items. You get the iterator started once with `.next()` and you also call `.next()` from the complete `callback` of your ajax request.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function request(item) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://httpbin.org/post',
            data: { myData: $(item).html() },
            complete: function() {
                //Simulate delay in the call, remove the setTimeout in your code
                setTimeout(function() {
                    //Once this call completes, call the next one
                    console.log('Call completed for item : ' + $(item).text());
                    iterator.next();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    function* ajaxGenerator(items) {
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            yield request(items[i]);
        }
    }

    var logItems = $('.logitem').get();
    var iterator = ajaxGenerator(logItems);

    //Get things started
    iterator.next();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="logitem">Item1</div>
    <div class="logitem">Item2</div>
    <div class="logitem">Item3</div>

</body>
</html>
```